# The Apache Tomcat installation at this directory is version 10.1.1. A Tomcat 10.0 installation is expected

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server, tomcat10

I am trying to add Tomcat 10.1.1 in Eclipse Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0).

[image]

Is there a newer version of Eclipse which have latest Tomcat?

Comment: Not yet, Batman. https://bugs.eclipse.org/575089.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening in older version of Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers. [This issue is corrected](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=575089) in the version 3.28 of Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers.

If you have the Standard Edition of Eclipse, you can add
'Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers'. This will add the version 3.22 of the software. You can then check for updates and update it to version 3.28